# Register new application in Azure AD manually

Tags: azure, active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-authentication

I am using VS 2015 to create new web application (.NET core) with Azure AD authentication. After I run the app, I see that Azure AD automatically register the new app for me. Then I can login successfully with my Azure user.

But I want to register my app manually. Therefore I followed the instruction on this site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-app-registration

Then I register my new application manually on Azure AD, and then update generated client Id to my appsettings.json, and then run and login with Azure user. I got the error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
MoveNext

AggregateException: Unhandled remote failure. (Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).)
MoveNext
```

Can some experts let me know the reason? I am new to Azure.
And one more question is I dont know why in my appsetting.json file there is no SecretKey?

[image: This is the screen when I created the app]

[image: This is my appsetting.json file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused the incorrect client secret for the app when you change the **appsettings.json** to the second app.

The sensitive data are stored in a JSON configuration file in the user profile directory:

Windows: %APPDATA%\microsoft\UserSecrets\\secrets.json

Linux: ~/.microsoft/usersecrets//secrets.json

Mac: ~/.microsoft/usersecrets//secrets.json

After you chagne **ClientSecret** in the secrets.json, the app should works well.

More detail about safe storage of app secrets during development, you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets).

Comment: Now it works and I understand. Thank you, Fei Xue, you are genious.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably **missing some delegation** rights (*not* application rights). Probably for the *Graph Api*.

Since you login using your Azure  account, the application performs request to e. g. Graph Api in behalf of your user (thats why you have to set delegation rights). Thats also the reason why you don't need a ClientSecret (you would need that if your application authenticate itself using a *service principal*).

Comment: Thanks Martin for your response. Actually I config the same for 2 apps, including ReplyURLs, Required Permission (use 2 Delete Permission: Sign in and Read User profile, Read directory data). The problem is after I changed to the second app registration, the web app navigate me to the Consent page again, then the error above appear when I click Accept button.